# C++ ignoring else statement

Tags: c++

making a program that allows the user to enter input so that they can get help with simple maths subjects. I thought I had made it so that had they entered a subject that wasn't there it would say so as (not) seen by the else statement below. Any idea why when I run it, it still includes the else statement when a input subject is correct? http://prntscr.com/ey3qyh

```
search = "triangle";

pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)
    // source http://www.mathopenref.com/triangle.html
    cout << "A closed figure consisting of three line segments linked end-to-end. A 3 - sided polygon." << endl;

search = "square";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)
    // source http://www.mathopenref.com/square.html
    cout << "A 4-sided regular polygon with all sides equal and all internal angles 90°" << endl;

else
    cout << "Sorry, it seems I have no information on this topic." << endl;

case 2:
    break;
default:
    cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Put `search = "square";` and everything after until `case 2:` into an `else` statement.  Then it only looks for a square if a triangle wasn't found.

Comment: There are more options than square or triangle, I just didn't want to include too much code. Would I put the else statement after the if of every search such as triangle and square and do as mentioned?

Comment: If you can change it so that all the code for the if is in the if statement (for example `search = "square";pos = sentence.find(search);if (pos != string::npos)` into `if (sentence.find("square") != string::npos)`) then you can change all the if statements after the first one into else if statements. If not then each if will have to be inside an else. I will write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two choices:

Nest the options so that each subsequent option is only evaluated when the previous one didn't work:

```
search = "triangle";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos){
    // link to info about triangle
    cout << "...info about triangle..." << endl;
}else{
    search = "square";
    pos = sentence.find(search);
    if (pos != string::npos){
        // link to info about square
        cout << "...info about square..." << endl;
    }else{
        search = "pentagon";
        pos = sentence.find(search);
        if (pos != string::npos){
            // link to info about pentagon
            cout << "...info about pentagon..." << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Sorry, it seems I have no information on this topic." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you can put all the code for the if's condition into the if statement you can used else if statements:

```
if (sentence.find("triangle") != string::npos){
    // link to info about triangle
    cout << "...info about triangle..." << endl;
}else if (sentence.find("square") != string::npos){
    // link to info about square
    cout << "...info about square..." << endl;
}else if (sentence.find("pentagon") != string::npos){
    // link to info about pentagon
    cout << "...info about pentagon..." << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Sorry, it seems I have no information on this topic." << endl;
}
```

Which one you used depends on if you can fit all the code for the if's condition into the condition itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went with the first option. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your program does:

- Looks for "triangle"
- If "triangle" is found, prints the definition of a triangle.
- Looks for "square"
- If "square" is found, prints the definition of a square. Otherwise, prints an apology.

Since "triangle" is found and "square" is not found, it prints the definition of a triangle and an apology. In other words, the computer is doing exactly what you told it to do - what is the problem?

Comment: Oh, okay. That's not how it's intended to be haha.
How would I change it so that it searches for triangle and only triangle? and if there's a definition stored it gives it, if not it lets the user search again for circle so say?

Comment: @j.doe By writing a program that does that... how exactly you want the program to look is up to you.